# Hide a modal form on submission in remixjs

Tags: modal-dialog, remix.run

I am working on a remix project at the moment, and I have a file that pretty much looks like this.

```
import { Button, Modal } from "flowbite-react";

import {useReducer} from "react";

export const loader = ({params, request}) => {
    // a bunch of stuff here;
}
export const action = ({request}) => {
    // a bunch of stuff here;
}

const MainComponent = () => {
    
    const initialState = {
        isDeleteModalOpen = false;
    }
    
    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        const obj = Object.assign({}, state);
        
        switch (action.type){
            case "showDeleteModal":{
                obj.isDeleteModalOpen = true;
                return obj;
            }
            case "hideDeleteModal":{
                obj.isDeleteModalOpen = false;
                return obj;
            }
        }
    }
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    return (

        <>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({type:"showDeleteModal"})}
            <React.Fragment>
                <Modal
                    show={isDeleteModalOpen}
                    onClose={() => dispatch({ type: "hideDeleteModal", id: "" })}
                    size="sm"
                    >
                    <Form method="post">
                        <Modal.Header>Are you sure?</Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            <div className="space-y-6">
                                <Alert color="failure" icon={HiInformationCircle}>
                                    <span>
                                        <span className="font-medium">Proceed with care! </span>{" "}
                                        This action could cause permanent data loss{" "}
                                    </span>
                                </Alert>
                            </div>
                        </Modal.Body>
                        <Modal.Footer>
                            <Button color="warning" type="submit">
                                Delete
                            </Button>

                            <Button
                                color="gray"
                                onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "hideDeleteModal" })}
                                >
                                Cancel
                            </Button>
                        </Modal.Footer>
                    </Form>
                </Modal>
            </React.Fragment>
        </>
    )

}

export default MainComponent;
```

The modal is controlled by the state, right now I am able to get the form working. However, after the submission it stays there because I never tell it to hide. While what I want actually is that the form goes away as the user submits it. Unfortunately, doing so inside a `useEffect` hook seems impossible.

I've done several research on this one but It seems I couldn't find any solution that covers similar case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close modal based on the `fetcher.data`.
if `fetcher data` is there then your form action is success you can close your modal now, if not `data` becomes `null` you can show respective UI.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue, the following is an example of how I handled it as it would apply to your code example.

```js
import { Form, useFetcher } from "@remix-run/react"
import { Alert, Button, Modal } from "flowbite-react"
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { HiInformationCircle } from "react-icons/hi"

export const loader = ({ params, request }) => {
  // a bunch of stuff here;
}
export const action = ({ request }) => {
  // a bunch of stuff here;
}

const MainComponent = () => {
  const fetcher = useFetcher()
  const [isDeleteModalOpen, setIsDeleteModalOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsDeleteModalOpen(true)} />
      <Modal
        show={isDeleteModalOpen}
        onClose={() => setIsDeleteModalOpen(false)}
        size="sm">
        <Form method="post">
          <Modal.Header>Are you sure?</Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <div className="space-y-6">
              <Alert
                color="failure"
                icon={HiInformationCircle}>
                <span>
                  <span className="font-medium">Proceed with care! </span> This action could cause
                  permanent data loss{" "}
                </span>
              </Alert>
            </div>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button
              color="warning"
              type="button" // <- Important bit - Could not get a working solution as "submit"
              onClick={(e) => {
                setIsDeleteModalOpen(false) // <- Order of ops in onClick is Important
                fetcher.submit(e.currentTarget) // <- Use fetcher to submit
              }}>
              Delete
            </Button>

            <Button
              color="gray"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => setIsDeleteModalOpen(false)}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}

export default MainComponent
```

This does remove the reducer as it's not required in order to achieve what is asked.  I've made the assumption that it was only there to handle the topic case.  Obviously if it's used elsewhere, you could still retain it to handle any other existing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the reloadDocument property in the Form component

```
<Form method="POST" className="flex gap-2" reloadDocument>
        <Input
          step="any"
          type="number"
          name={modal?.nameInput}
          className="flex-1"
        />
        <Button className="flex-1" type="submit">
          Save
        </Button>
</Form>
```

It forces a full document navigation and that will close the modal.
Link to documentation:
https://remix.run/docs/en/main/components/form#reloaddocument

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to have the `useReducer()`, you can use a combination of remix [`useNavigation()`](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-navigation) and [`useActionData()`](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-action-data) hooks to derivate the state you want.

If you want to display your modal until your action respond, you can do it using `navigation` to display a pending state and the `actionData` to effectively close the modal

```
const Component = () => {
  const data = useActionData()
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  // you can check if your action respond correctly here
  // here ok is a boolean returned by my action
  const isOpen = !data?.ok
  const isLoading = navigation.state !== 'submitting'

  return <Modal loading={isLoading} show={isOpen} />
}
```